# Javafx Disable Scrolling by Mousewheel in ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, mousewheel, scrollpane

Does anayone know how to disable scrolling by Mousewheel in a ScrollPane?

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
    scrollPane.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
            if (event.getDeltaY() > 0) {
                zoomIn();
            } else {
                zoomOut();
            }
            event.consume();
        }});
```

You may find that you also need something like the following:

```
scrollPane.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
        if (event.getDeltaY() > 0) {
            zoomIn();
        } else {
            zoomOut();
        }
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

I added the above elaboration to another answer in this thread, but it hasn't shown up in the public feed from what I can tell.  So, I've pasted it in its own answer.

This question is a bit of a duplicate, but it showed up in Google for me first, so I'm answering it.  The inspiration for the above is:

[Zooming in JavaFx: ScrollEvent is consumed when content size exceeds ScrollPane viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238507/zooming-in-javafx-scrollevent-is-consumed-when-content-size-exceeds-scrollpane)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no direct solution.

So I would [add an event filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventFilter-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-) to the ScrollPane for the [SCROLL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html#SCROLL) EventType and consume every event. That should prevent any mouse generated scroll events from being delegated to the ScrollPane.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This helps me for now. But what if I want to enable scrolling on an element within the scrollpane. For example a TableView?

Comment: You can check the event target of the `ScrollEvent` and only consume it, if it matches your criteria.

Comment: I tried it, but the event target is every time the scrollpane. :(

Comment: When I know how to push panes behind each other, my problem is solved, too. Because my main idea is to slide panes in and out, I tried it with a GridPane within a Stackpane, but when I move the gridpane (this is how I implemented the sliding effect), it's always in front of other views. With a Scrollpane I don't have this problem.

Comment: You can use `toFront()` or `toBack()` to move component z-order. Also you can have a look at the `Pagination` control for sliding in and out components.

Comment: Ok, now I tried also the toFront() and toBack() methode, but this doesn't work, too. The problem is that the content, which have to be in the front is in the head of a borderPane and the gridPane is in the center of the borderPane. So the z-order does not seem to be relevant for that.

Comment: Yeeeaaaahh, I solved the problem! The solution is `setClip()` methode. Here is the hole solution:

`Rectangle clipRectangle = new Rectangle();
 clipRectangle.widthProperty().bind(contentPane.widthProperty());
 clipRectangle.heightProperty().bind(contentPane.heightProperty());
 contentPane.setClip(clipRectangle);`

Comment: @Studiosus you should answer on your own question if you found a solution for your answer. This helps other people who are searching for this